# How to access the +/- dialog to modify a number (like when setting the time)

Tags: android

If you pop open the clock application and set the alarm you get a nifty pop-up with the time that you can modify using + and - buttons.  I'm wondering if there's that's a standard and, if so, if there's an easy way to access it so that it pops up when clicking on an element in a ListView?

[image: plus/minus dialog]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is **not** a standard view in Android, so you will have to make it yourself. :-)